# Rails 5 how to handle response to show flash success/error messages, if form submitted with remote true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. Rails 5 how to handle response to show flash success/error messages,
   if form submitted with remote true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a partial in your view, I would recommend create a views/shared folder

> app/views/shared/_flash.html.erb

```
<div id="flash-messages">
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div class="alert text-center alert-<%= flash_class_name(message_type) %> alert-dismissable mb-0">
      <span><%= message %></span>
      <button type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

add this line to your layout file (in body)

> app/views/application.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/flash' %>
```

now in related action view file

> app/views/[controller]/[create/update].js.erb

```
$('#flash-messages').html("<%= j render 'shared/flash' %>");
```

and your controller action add flash like this

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Request was saved successfully.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remote true causes rails to submit the form with ajax, so you can handle the request on the frontend

```
$(document).ready(() =>
  function showFlash(message, color) {
    // Handle finding your flash
    // clear it, set color and message
  }
  $("#your_selector").on("ajax:success", function(event) {
    const [data, status, xhr] = Array.from(event.detail);
    showFlash(xhr.responseText, 'green');
  }).on("ajax:error", function(event) {
    showFlash('Sorry there was an error', 'green')
  })
);
```

With the above you can get a lot more fancy but should at least give you the bones to work with.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html